# How to decode an Android binary dictionary to a human readable format like .xml

Tags: android, dictionary, binary, decode

I have a .dict directory with files that contain bigrams for my personalized keyboard suggestions. From looking around the [Android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/personalization/) I've gathered that the files are encoded in a binary dictionary format, described [here](https://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/wiki/BinaryDictionaries). That wiki page describes how to convert .xml files to .dict binary dictionaries, but not how to convert binary dictionaries to a human readable format. Is the only way to extract human readable data from these files to use the functions in the Android source?

Here are the files in question:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if this will help at all, but in reference to your statement "Would be excellent to have some java code showing how to read words from the binary dictionary", maybe [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/android-4.1.2_r2/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/BinaryDictionaryGetter.java) would be a good start. [This is the GIT](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/android-4.1.2_r2/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/BinaryDictionaryGetter.java)

It says that it returns a word list but I am not sure what format it returns it in nor how it would look. This code snippet is from line 240 on this page.

```
> * Returns the list of cached files for a specific locale, one for each category.
>      *
>      * This will return exactly one file for each word list category that matches
>      * the passed locale. If several files match the locale for any given category,
>      * this returns the file with the closest match to the locale. For example, if
>      * the passed word list is en_US, and for a category we have an en and an en_US
>      * word list available, we'll return only the en_US one.
>      * Thus, the list will contain as many files as there are categories.
>      *
>      * @param locale the locale to find the dictionary files for, as a string.
>      * @param context the context on which to open the files upon.
>      * @return an array of binary dictionary files, which may be empty but may not be null.
>      */
>     private static File[] getCachedWordLists(final String locale,
>             final Context context) {
>         final File[] directoryList = getCachedDirectoryList(context);
>         if (null == directoryList) return EMPTY_FILE_ARRAY;
>         final HashMap<String, FileAndMatchLevel> cacheFiles =
>                 new HashMap<String, FileAndMatchLevel>();
>         for (File directory : directoryList) {
>             if (!directory.isDirectory()) continue;
>             final String dirLocale = getWordListIdFromFileName(directory.getName());
>             final int matchLevel = LocaleUtils.getMatchLevel(dirLocale, locale);
>             if (LocaleUtils.isMatch(matchLevel)) {
>                 final File[] wordLists = directory.listFiles();
>                 if (null != wordLists) {
>                     for (File wordList : wordLists) {
>                         final String category = getCategoryFromFileName(wordList.getName());
>                         final FileAndMatchLevel currentBestMatch = cacheFiles.get(category);
>                         if (null == currentBestMatch || currentBestMatch.mMatchLevel < matchLevel) {
>                             cacheFiles.put(category, new FileAndMatchLevel(wordList, matchLevel));
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         if (cacheFiles.isEmpty()) return EMPTY_FILE_ARRAY;
>         final File[] result = new File[cacheFiles.size()];
>         int index = 0;
>         for (final FileAndMatchLevel entry : cacheFiles.values()) {
>             result[index++] = entry.mFile;
>         }
>         return result;
>     }
```

As for how to convert the .dict binary file to a human readable form, I know that this is not what you're looking for specifically, but maybe it will give you a good start. It looks like you might have to write something yourself to make the conversion as they did [Here](https://github.com/windylea/lingoes-converter). They wrote this script to handle this process.

> "Lingoes Converter is a script written in PHP that can convert
>   .LD2/.LDX dictionaries of Lingoes into human-readable text files. The
>   script is based on Xiaoyun Zhu analysis (lingoes-extractor) on the
>   LD2/LDX dictionary format ."

I hope that maybe some of this will at least give you a start. That is a niche need that definitely needs a good solution provided. I hope you figure it out!

Comment: This gives me a good start. I'm planning on writing something similar to Lingoes Converter and releasing it on GitHub. I really appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: @Miles, have ou got any results? I am having the same problem but can't find solution.

Comment: @AndreyRudenko Hi Andrey. Yes, I was able to decode it using the command line utility dicttool in packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/tools/dicttool. There's more info about how to do that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949865/latinime-dicttool-for-use-with-a-v401-binary-dictionary). I believe I had to compile the dicttool using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/what-docker).

Comment: Miles, can you share the compiled dicttool?