# LatinIME dicttool for use with a V401 Binary Dictionary

Tags: java, android, c++, dictionary

I’m trying to convert a version 401 [binary dictionary](https://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/wiki/BinaryDictionaries) -- a directory called PersonalizationDictionary.en_US.dict -- to human readable .xml.

The command line utility dicttool_aosp in packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/tools/dicttool can do it like so:

```
dicttool_aosp makedict -s sourcedict.dict -x output.xml
```

I’m unable to compile the Android Lollipop version of dicttool, since dicttool has native C++ dependencies that don’t play nice with my Mac. Note this line in the NativeLib.mk file of dictool:

```
HACK: Temporarily disable host tool build on Mac until the build system is ready for C++11.
```

I am hoping someone with a compatible setup can compile this utility for me using “make dicttool_aosp” from the root of the AOSP source tree. I've spent the past few days looking for compiled versions of it, and while I’ve found many makedict.jar files online, they are too old to support my newer V401 binary dictionary. The main difference between the V401 and older versions is that a V401 is split up into multiple files with extensions like .bigrams, .freq, .header, whereas the older dicts are contained in a single file.

Thank you, please let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I might be able to help you.